# How to Tokenize String without using strtok()

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize a string without using a `strtok()`.

When I run characters of string, it will print in each line.

For instance, when I run:

```
printfTokens("Hello from other side!");
```

The output should be:

```
Hello
from 
other
side!
```

As I'm just learning C, I'm stuck for hours on how to implement this program. So far, I only know the basics and playing around with not (still haven't learned any `calloc`, `mallo`c, etc).

So far I have this code, but the output does not print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD 100

void printfTokens(char *inputString) {

    int i;

    /*int inputStringLength;

    for(i = 0; inputString[i] != '/0'; i++) {
        inputStringLength++;
    }*/

    while(inputString[i] != '\0') {
        char testing[MAX_WORD];
        while(inputString[i] != ' ') {
            testing[inputString[i]]++;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s", testing);
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {

    printfTokens("TESTING ONE! TWO! THREE!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what the line `testing[inputString[i]]++;` does. Is it what you want?

Comment: I want to add each character one by one, so I guess I need to change to testing[inputString[i]++]? Still bit confusing..

Comment: what does ++ do? What does inputString[i] do? What does testing[something] do?

Comment: I used ++ to add each character in a word and inputString[i] is each character in the string. I created testing character array to add each array character.

Comment: ++ does no such thing as "adding a character in a word". Did you learn what ++ does? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not initialize the variable `i`.
2. `while(inputString[i] != '\0')` can be written `while(inputString[i])`.
3. `testing[inputString[i]]++` makes sense to count the number of occurrences of a given character from `inputString`, but it does not make sense to print it.  You may want to do something like:

   ```
   while(1) 
   {
    char testing[MAX_WORD], *t=testing;
    while(inputString[i]&&(inputString[i]!=' '))
        *t++=inputString[i++];
    if (t>testing) printf("%s", testing);
    if (!inputString[i]) break;
    i++;
   }
   ```
4. It would be better to name `MAX_WORD_LENGTH` instead of `MAX_WORD`.

These are a few problems in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! For #3, may I ask what I should do instead?

Comment: @Muzzlet update

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! In this function, then should the print statement be printf("%s", *t); outside the while loop?

Comment: @Muzzlet update again

Answer (score 0):

Sample tokenization function.

```
size_t tokenize(const char *inputString, const char *delim, char **argv, size_t maxtokens) 
{
    size_t ntokens = 0;
    char *tokenized = strdup(inputString);
    if(tokenized)
    {
        argv[0] = tokenized;
        while(*tokenized)
        {
            if(strchr(delim, *tokenized))
            {
                *tokenized = 0;
                ntokens++;
                if(ntokens == maxtokens - 1) 
                {
                    break;
                }
                argv[ntokens] = tokenized + 1;
            }
            tokenized++;
        }
    }
    return ntokens + 1;
}

int main() 
{
    char *tokens[10];
    size_t ntokens = tokenize("TESTING ONE! TWO! THREE!", " ", tokens , 10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ntokens; i++)
    {
        printf("Token[%zu] = `%s`\n", i, tokens[i]);
    }
    free(tokens[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/znv8PszG6